# Matlab Taking Particular Rows From Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, cross-validation

I am working on implementing cross validation at Matlab without using any other functions except for native ones.

I have a matrix like that:

```
1
2
3
..
N
```

I have a fold size **M**

At first iteration I want to take that:

```
1
2
3
..
N-M
```

at second iteration:

```
1
2
3
..
.. //Number o f M elements didn't included here
N-M+1
N-M+2
..
N
```

iterate until I process

```
M+1
M+2
..
N
```

When I don't include any set of elements I want to assign them into another variable or I want to know indexes so I can process them (this one is better for performance)

Further information about cross validation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

This graphic explains what I want(form Georgia Tech University slides):
[image]

I am new to matlab, how can I implement it easily?

Comment: You lost me on the second iteration... Are you simply trying to partition your vector into K subsets?

Comment: At second iteration I have 2 subsets. One of them is size of M, other one is size of N-M

Comment: @jerad I have included a graphic that explains what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bit of code will segment your data as illustrated in your graphic.

```
K = 5; %Fold size
N = 25; % Number of data points

data = rand(1,N); % Some fake data

testIdxs = reshape(1:N,K, N/k)'; %now each row has the indices for one test set

% All indices that aren't in the test, should belong to the training set. 
trainIdx = zeros(K, N-K);
for ix = 1:N/k
    temp                = 1:25;
    temp(testIdxs(ix,:)) = [];
    trainIdx(ix,:)      = temp;
end
```

Keep in mind that this method only works if N is a multiple of K.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Validation in general can be done through the function [crossvalind](http://www.mathworks.in/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html).

You can do it by

```
Indices = crossvalind('Kfold', matrix , M)
```

Comment: ...which is in the Bioinformatics toolbox and thus *not* "native" Matlab, as the OP requested.